# H20 - R (Time is parsed incorrectly when importing from CSV)

Tags: r, date, h2o

I'm uploading a `.csv` file in R-H2o using `h2o.importFile`. However, the date values are parsed incorrectly.

For example, with date time format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, (e.g. `2016-06-16 12:30:00`), the result is always `1466073000000`, which is incorrect.

Comment: This is probably milliseconds since epoch.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd combinations of data import artifacts:

This is an epoch time, which is in number of seconds from January 1, 1970.

If you use this code:

```
numDate <- 1466073000 #notice I removed three zeros
as.POSIXct(numDate, origin="1970-01-01")
```

You get the following output:

```
"2016-06-16 06:30:00 EDT"
```

So, it is in miliseconds.
Also, the time is incorrect, by 6 hours.

Chances are it is giving you Greenwich mean time adjustment for your systems time zone (which if you work in a corporate system could be different than your current time zone depending on where the actual processor is located and how your system is set up)

You have options:

Run the analysis on epoch time
or
Convert using:

`as.POSIXct( 1466073000000/1000, origin="1970-01-01")`

try to coerce h2o to bring it in the way you want.

As long as this time (with your zone adjustment) IS correct there is no reason to change it unless you need to be able to read it correctly. I would change the output after the analysis was run to make it human readable.

Comment: Thanks for the intel, that does help. However, h2o tends to parse time incorrectly. For example, a CSV that has dates in the format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm, the complier not only adds milliseconds, with the extra 1000 like you showed, it also gives an NaN for good chunk of the values.